# Java convert an int into hours and minutes

Tags: java, time

I have two ints 1530 and 830 which is supposed to represent 15:30 and 8:30 in time. What is the best way to convert this number into milliseconds? I was thinking of converting them into strings and sub strings but this seems like a very inefficient approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int mins = yourint % 100;
int hours = yourint / 100;  
long timeInMillis = mins * 60000L + hours * 360000L;
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response, I was going about completely wrong

Answer (score 7):

```
int twentyFourHourTimeToMilliseconds(int time) {
    int hours = time / 100;
    int minutes = time % 100;
    return ((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
( x / 100 ) * 3600000L + (x % 100) * 60000L
```

Answer (score 0):

Or see java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit